# Is there a way to accept multipart forms on meteorjs? i.e. image uploads?

Tags: node.js, upload, meteor

I want to be able to add image uploads to a site I'm working on, but I don't know how that is supposed to work with meteorjs. Is there a way to accept multipart forms on meteorjs? i.e. image uploads?

I could always rackup a small sinatra app for file uploads but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like eventminded has a file upload package you could use.
https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-file-upload-package

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a middleware to accept such requests.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
    route: '/your/url/for/inputs',
    handle: function(req, res, next) {

        // Handle request and response
        // just like you would do in node.js.

        // Make sure to wrap your db calls in Fibers.

        // Use next() if you change your mind
        // and don't want to handle this request after all.

    },
});
```

Comment: This is of course true too, its just the link above is more in depth, unfortunately I can't check both, and I don't have a high enough rating to press the up arrow.